# наличие класса в файле php

Tags: php

Как проверить существует ли класс в файле?

Этим кодом я выбираю все файлы:

```
$dir = WWW.'/libs';
$arrayLibs = array();

if($handle = opendir($dir)){

    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
            //$arrayLibs[] = $file;
            if (class_exists($file)) {
                $arrayLibs[] = __CLASS__;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В этом же цикле хочу проверять в каждом файле существует ли класс (любой, не какой-то определенный) и выводить его название, если он существует.

Comment: Можно, конечно, сначала проверить существование класса class_exists() убедиться, что его нет, потом include файл и снова проверить class_exists() - но, наверное, это немного не то.

Answer (score 10):

Самый надежный вариант - использовать [token_get_all](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.token-get-all.php)

Как-то так:

```
$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents(file));
$classStart = false;
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if ($token[0] === T_CLASS) {
        $classStart = true;
    }
    if ($classStart && $token[0] === T_STRING) {
        $class = $token[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Более развернутый пример поиска класса(с пространством имен) в файле можете посмотреть у меня в [проекте на гитхабе](https://github.com/rjhdby/php-api-skeleton/blob/master/src/class/core/Controller.php)

Comment: @rjhbdy, сильно

Comment: Интересная функция, спасибо! Что побудило её ввести в проду...?

Comment: @Aid Как раз для подобных случаев - язык то динамически компилируемый, работающий на сырых исходниках, сталобыть почему бы и нет?

Comment: Это да, однако "почему бы нет" - весьма недальновидное решение для подобных продуктов. Это же не домашний проектик, тут каждый шаг должен иметь сакральный или, хотя бы, финансовый смысл. Хотя в пыхе таких странностей навалом...

Comment: @Aid Если вспомнить историю PHP, то начинался он именно что как домашний проектик и до сих пор в большОй своей части развивается таки сообществом

Answer (score 1):

Можно парсить каждый файл и проверять следующим образом, есть ли в нем классы. Наверно это костыль, но рабочий:

```
<?php

 $data = file_get_contents('file.php');

 preg_match_all('/class [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*/', $data, $matches);

 if (!empty($matches[0])) {
     foreach ($matches[0] as $val) {
         var_dump(substr($val, 6));
     }
 }
```

Comment: а если там будет так `$a = 'This class of letters bla-bla-bla'`?

Comment: не сработал костыль, файл есть, класс в файле тоже есть но ничего не выводится

Comment: @rjhdby, спасибо за замечание

Comment: @privetsh покажите пример своего файла

Comment: @privetsh, была опечатка. Исправил, можете еще раз попробовать

Comment: да, сработало, использую Ваш вариант спасибо!

Comment: как убрать слово class из регулрки, потому что с ним результат Array ( [0] => class validateForms [1] => class markerImages )  а без него Array ( [0] => php [1] => class [2] => validateForms [3] => public [4] => function [5] => FormData [6] => data [7] => echo [8] => data [9] => Fuck [10] => php [11] => class [12] => markerImages [13] => public [14] => function [15] => markerIMG [16] => data [17] => return [18] => data [19] => Fuck )  а мне нужен результат: Array ( [0] => validateForms [1] => markerImages )

Comment: @privetsh, внес правку, попробуйте с ней

Comment: ну да )) логично ... самому слабо дойти (я о себе ) ) спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

я сдела таким образом, он отрабаывает прекрастно:

```
$dir = WWW.'/libs';
$arrayLibs = array();

if($handle = opendir($dir)){

    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
            $className = substr($file, 0, -4);
            require_once $dir.'/'.$file;
            if (class_exists($className)) $arrayLibs[] = 'Class name: '.$className;
            else $arrayLibs[] = 'Class <b>'.$className.'</b> dont exist';
        }
    }
}

print_r($arrayLibs);
```

Comment: 1) Работает только если имя файла соответствует классу, что далеко не всегда так. 2) Если в двух файлах будут классы с одним и тем-же именем, то будет печалька 3) Данное решение дает побочные эффекты, а именно загрузку всех классов в контекст исполнения скрипта, что не факт, что нужно

Comment: по идее они будут записываться только в определенный массив и вызываться по необходимости, и имя файлов обязательно должны совпадать с именами классов. поэтому совпадений быть почти не должно